# Microsoft Bookings Graph APi Invalid filter clause

Tags: c#, filter, graph

I try to filter Microsoft Booking webapi customer endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list-customers?view=graph-rest-1.0) using the 1.0 C# Graph SDK based on customer email attribute, but the query always fails with invalid filter clause.
This is the filter expression:

```
var filterexpression = $"emailAddress eq 'stackoverflow@gmail.com'";
```

This is the query which using it:

```
            var customersCollection = await Resilience.Retry(() => _serviceClient.Solutions.BookingBusinesses[bookingbusiness].Customers
                .Request().Filter(filterexpression)
                .GetAsync());
```

Is filtering supported on bookings api endpoints, and if yes, what is went wrong here?

Comment: I don't use this part of Graph, but your query looks good. So it seems that filtering in general or at least on mail address is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the test in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) only `id` property supports filtering.

Other properties like `displayName`, `emailAddress`, `addresses` and `phones` are not filterable right now.